# How to distinguish between Base Class and Derived Class in generics using Typing and Mypy

Tags: python, generics, mypy, python-typing

Consider the following code:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    pass


@dataclasses.dataclass
class B(A):
    pass


T = TypeVar("T", A, B)


def fun(
    x1: T,
    x2: T,
) -> int:
    if type(x1) != type(x2):
        raise TypeError("must be same type!")

    if type(x1) == A:
        return 5

    elif type(x1) == B:
        return 10
    else:
        raise TypeError("Type not handled")


fun(x1=A(), x2=A())  # OK
fun(x1=B(), x2=B())  # OK
fun(x1=B(), x2=A())  # Will throw TypeError, how can I get mypy to say this is an error?
fun(x1=A(), x2=B())  # Will throw TypeError, how can I get mypy to say this is an error?
```

Mypy is not seeing any problem here. It seems like it is always interpreting the passed object as a base class object of type `A`.

Is there a way to make the generic even more strict in the sense that it is sensitive to the exact class type? Such that if `x1` is of type `B`, then also `x2` must be exactly of type `B`? If `x1` is of type `A` then also `x2` must be exactly of type `A`?

Comment: fwiw this isn't how class polymorphism works. If you accept an `A` you should also accept a `B`. Thus, accepting two `A`s should mean all combinations are allowed. It might help to know _why_ you want this

Comment: Totally, I understand that point. My question is, ia it possible to encode what I am checking for dynam8cally into the typesystem. Date and datetime... are not compatible, but datete inherits from date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a fun question - at first I considered solving it in the following way:

```py
from typing import overload
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    pass


@dataclasses.dataclass
class B(A):
    pass


@overload
def fun(x1: B, x2: B) -> int:
    ...


@overload
def fun(x1: A, x2: A) -> int:
    ...


def fun(
    x1: A | B,
    x2: A | B,
) -> int:
    if type(x1) != type(x2):
        raise TypeError("must be same type!")

    if type(x1) == A:
        return 5

    elif type(x1) == B:
        return 10
    else:
        raise TypeError("Type not handled")


fun(x1=A(), x2=A())
fun(x1=B(), x2=B())
fun(x1=B(), x2=A())
fun(x1=A(), x2=B())
```

I thought this might be a quirk of the way `TypeVar` works initially, but I discovered that even if we specify in an overload, that it must be `A, A` or `B, B` then it still won't raise an error on the final two lines. The last two just use the overload `A, A`, because `A, B` is still a subtype of `A, A`. Python does not distinguish at all between direct instances and subtypes - you could enforce a structural type with a `Protocol`, so long as there was a structural difference between A and B.

Even if you made the function arg a `list[A]`, B's would still be valid in the list for this reason.

If you're trying to get B to pick to up all the attributes of A, and have them be distinct types, I would instead do it this way, with A being now a hidden base class, and A2 exposed to an end user:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    pass


@dataclasses.dataclass
class B(A):
    pass

@dataclasses.dataclass
class A2(A):
    # Note, this class would be empty in practice as well
    pass



T = TypeVar("T", A2, B)

def fun(
    x1: T,
    x2: T,
) -> int:
    if type(x1) != type(x2):
        raise TypeError("must be same type!")

    if type(x1) == A2:
        return 5

    elif type(x1) == B:
        return 10
    else:
        raise TypeError("Type not handled")


fun(x1=A2(), x2=A2())  # OK
fun(x1=B(), x2=B())  # OK
fun(x1=B(), x2=A2())  # Will throw TypeError, how can I get mypy to say this is an error?
fun(x1=A2(), x2=B())  # Will throw TypeError, how can I get mypy to say this is an error?
```

Hope this is useful!

Comment: Ah great idea! I like the solution!